# Kubernetes, Code Snippet to scale up / down pods dynamically through go client

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

Is there any sample code available to scale up / down pods in kubernetes dynamically through go client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out [this](https://github.com/LiliC/kube-start-stop) sample github project with kube-start-stop custom controller, that can schedule your resources to automatically scale down/up based on time period.

Comment: I am writing the client for scale up / down the pods using go-client for kubernetes, i encountered the following error "Error deployments.extensions \"my-deployment\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot update deployments.extensions in the namespace \"default\"".

Comment: How  does your go-client accesses Kubernetes clsuter, from inside or outside ?
I assumed you have RBAC enabled, so have granted a default service account a edit permissions, like this ?
kubectl create clusterrolebinding default-view --clusterrole=edit --serviceaccount=default:default